# Mockito test works but Android Studio cannot resolve reference to it

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, mockito, kotlin-multiplatform

I have [forked](https://github.com/OskarPersson/kmm-basic-sample) the [KMM basic sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-basic-sample) and added [Mockito Kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin).

The following test works as expected when executed:

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

import org.mockito.kotlin.*

class CalculatorTest {
    @Test
    fun testMock() {
        val mockGen = mock<Generator> {
            on { gen() } doReturn "mocked"
        }
        assertEquals("bar", Calculator(DefaultGenerator()).foo())
        assertEquals("mocked", Calculator(mockGen).foo())
    }
}
```

But why does Android Studio complain that it can't resolve the reference to mockito:

[image]

I have updated Android Studio to the latest version, tried the Canary channel and deleted the `.idea` directory.

Comment: when you say the test works, are you executing it from Android Studio directly (by clicking on the "play" button) or by manually executing the corresponding Gradle task?

Comment: Yes I am, works without any problems.

Comment: which of the 2 are you using?

Comment: Oh shit, sorry. I am executing it from Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing tests in common code, the dependency won't be found because it is a JVM-only dependency. It will run when you run a JVM test. For common code, you'll need a mocking library compatible with native targets (I'm assuming Android and iOS are your targets). However, all mocking libraries for native are restricted to interfaces and open classes, so they likely won't work as you're used to.

Comment: what you said is right, but then why are the tests successful according to the OP?

Comment: So how can I solve my case where I want to use specifically mockito for my shared code? Is the best approach to write a separate Kotlin library? Would that solve it?